# Leaderboard Command with Discordpy and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a leaderboard command, but it's not working. Does anybody see anything wrong with my code, and if so, can you tell me how to fix it?

```py
    @challenge.command(aliases=['leaderboard'])
    async def lb(self, ctx):
        lb_data = main_db['challenges'].find().sort("total_points", -1)
        embed = discord.Embed(title='**Challenge Leaderboard**',
                            description='''description msg''', color=discord.Colour.red())
        for i, x in enumerate(lb_data, 1):
            embed.add_field(name=f"#{i}", value=f"<@{str(x['id'])}> has {str(x['total_points'])}",
                            inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: What about it isn't working? Do you get an error?

Comment: I get the error 
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'total_points'
This is confusing to me as I know it exists and have referenced it in other commands.

Comment: What do you get back from `main_db['challenges'].find()`?

Comment: <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x07033D90>

Comment: Is it possible for a document to *not* have the `total_points` field?

Comment: There are currently 2 documents with total_points and 1 without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your'e getting a [KeyError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) because there's a document without the `total_points` field in it.

You can do a check beforehand to avoid this error. It might look like this:

```py
for i, x in enumerate(lb_data, 1):
    if 'total_points' in x:
        total_points = str(x['total_points'])
    else:
        total_points = "0"
    embed.add_field(name=f"#{i}", value=f"<@{str(x['id'])}> has {total_points}", inline=False)
```